# Creating a table-row caption with table-layout (faking the colspan for table-layout)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working with an existing div with table layout, as can be seen in the attached fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/hgLc7tuz/1/

What I need to achieve is the following:

- The caption div should be put below each row and should have no effect on the table layout (it should not be included in how the table cell width is calculated)
- Table cells should be vertically aligned
- Positioning of the caption div cannot be achieved by using the absolute positioning as I need the table to grow if the caption is too long.
- Using the table tag is also not an option as I work with legacy code

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.row{
  display: table-row;
}

.cell{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">First</div>
    <div class="cell">Hello stackoverflow</div>
    <div class="caption">I am the row caption</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">I am second</div>
    <div class="cell">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="caption">I am the row caption</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">Hello</div>
    <div class="caption">I am the row caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am aware that the colspan function is not available when table layout is used and I have searched for existing suggestions but nothing seems to work in my case.
I tried the following:

- adding the caption as a table-row, but this influenced the layout of the cells above
- using a nested table for the caption, and setting it as the table-caption but the width was incorrect again

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Both the HTML and CSS inside your question, are significantly different from what your fiddle contains. So which of the two versions are we supposed to discuss now?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save the fiddle changes, now both the code and fiddle should match

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution using the `fit-content` attribute. Changed the row structure for a little bit, and add some extra inline css. Please check and let me now if I missunderstanding something.

```css
        .table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row{
  display: table-row;
}

.cell{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div style="width:fit-content">
  <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">First</div>
                    <div class="cell">Hello stackoverflow</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>I am the row captiofggggggggggggggfffffffffgggggggn</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">First</div>
                    <div class="cell">Hello stackoverflowsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>I am the row captiofggggggggggggggffffffdddddfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggn</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">First</div>
                    <div class="cell">Hello stackoverflow</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>I am the row captiofggggggggggggggfffffffffgggggggn</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the table cols (cells) need to be vertically aligned as well which in this case is not really achieved :(

Comment: I have now edited the question so that the vertical alignment requirement is visible from the beginning